# Spring boot unable to connect redis client Jedis to pool: Connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis, connection-refused

I'm new to Spring boot development and all I want is to enable a Session for an Admin user. I'm writing a REST stateless (API) and a stateful service and I'm following a tutorial which is using redis in-memory-database for storing user sessions. I'm already using MySQL/JDBC for storing other data. Using redis and jdbc doesn't conflict?

In order to enable user session, I made the following:

These are the dependencies that I have added lately:

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Creating a Jedis Connection Factory:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

And the secured `http` configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

I have also added the redis connection hostname and port in the `application.properties`:

```
# ===============================
# = REDIS
# ===============================
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

However, when I run the application, the following error is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

I have tried to change `localhost` to `192.168.1.2` (my PC's local IP), tried to change the port but the connection is still refused.

This is the stacktrace first line:

```
[restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

I don't know what else I could do. I'm having an antivirus (Windows). Should I disable it? Should I disable the firewall? Should I scan the ports to see what ports are opened?

**Edit**:
I have already tried using redis standalone configuration to pass the hostname and the port, but still can't connect:

```
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 6379);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Jedis' connection pool:

```
spring:
  redis:
    client-type: jedis
    jedis:
      pool:
        enabled: true
        max-active: 4
        max-idle: 4
        max-wait: -10ms
        min-idle: 0
```

Answer (score -3):

If it is localhost. Try with 127.0.0.1:****

Sometimes using ip (192.168.x.x) can give errors ...

```
# ===============================
# = REDIS
# ===============================
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.redis.port=6379
```

Comment: I had to use Google Translate to translate your message, anyways. I have tried to connect using that IP 127.0.0.1 but I still can't connect. I have edited my message.